# Read data from postgres in order of a row

Tags: python, postgresql

```
Open    High    Low     Close   Date
25.01   25.16   24.93   24.98   "2019-12-03"
25.28   25.32   25.04   25.13   "2019-12-02"
25.40   25.40   25.18   25.25   "2019-11-29"
19.70   19.85   19.60   19.74   "2020-05-06"
19.65   19.81   19.65   19.70   "2020-05-05"
19.45   19.78   19.32   19.57   "2020-05-04"
19.87   20.15   19.60   19.96   "2020-04-30"
```

This is the arrangement of data in my table. I want to read the data using python in a way that the most recent date appears first. However, because I inserted the bottom 4 rows later than the three rows they are at the bottom of table. So I when read my data it displays in the arrangement shown above where the first row in the table gets shown first instead of the data in the fourth row.

```
import psycopg2

try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                  password="limhy0809",
                                  host="127.0.0.1",
                                  port="5432",
                                  database="datascraping")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    postgreSQL_select_Query = "select * from stock_ticker_price"

    cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
    print("Selecting rows from stock_ticker_price table using cursor.fetchall")
    mobile_records = cursor.fetchall()

    print("Print each row and it's columns values")
    for row in mobile_records:
        print("Date: ", row[6], )
        print("Open: ", row[2])
        print("Close: ", row[5], "\n")

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
    print("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)

finally:
    # closing database connection.
    if(connection):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

This is my current code

Comment: just add `order by "Date" desc` to your query

Comment: Got it thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `order by` to your query:

```
postgreSQL_select_Query = 'select * from stock_ticker_price order by "Date" desc'
```